# Dummying a dataset in R in a vectorized manner

Tags: r, dataset

I'm working with a 'weighted' adjacency matrix to a graph. It represents connections or relationships between entities. Since it's weighted it has different values, 0 being no relationship and goes up adding connection between the entities.
I've been thinking about how to make a new dataset, similar to this one but only with 0s and 1s. 
So this:

```
  A B C D E                        A B C D E 
A 0 2 5 1 9                      A 0 1 1 1 1 
B 3 0 1 0 0    goes into this:   B 1 0 1 0 0
C 0 0 0 3 4                      C 0 0 0 1 1
D 0 4 5 0 2                      D 0 1 1 0 1
E 0 1 2 3 0                      E 0 1 1 1 0
```

I've been wondering how to do it, and only came up with a for-loop-solution that seems far from optimal and non-vectorized. I would appreciate any insight from an R enlightened one in order to come up with a more elegant answer.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that avoids loops.

```
> tab1 <- rbind(c(0, 2, 5, 1, 9),
+               c(3, 0, 1, 0, 0),
+               c(0, 0, 0, 3, 4),
+               c(0, 4, 5, 0, 2),
+               c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0))
> tab2 <- matrix(as.numeric(tab1!=0), 
+                nrow=nrow(tab1), ncol=ncol(tab1))
> 
> tab1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    5    1    9
[2,]    3    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    3    4
[4,]    0    4    5    0    2
[5,]    0    1    2    3    0
> tab2
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0    1
[5,]    0    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: Just `tab2<-(tab1!=0)*1` is enough. Dimensions will survive comparison.

Comment: @mbq: Good point!

Answer (score 2):

@mbq and @robermorales point out that this can be done with functions that maintain the matrix nature of the data automatically, and @ocram shows how to cast the data back to a matrix of the appropriate dimension were the function to not preserve the dimensions.  I wanted to show another approach which works even if the transformation would not preserve dimensions.

Starting with the data provided

```
tab1 <- rbind(c(0, 2, 5, 1, 9),
              c(3, 0, 1, 0, 0),
              c(0, 0, 0, 3, 4),
              c(0, 4, 5, 0, 2),
              c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0))
```

You can use `apply` over both margins to work on each element at a time, and `apply` will guarantee the matrix nature is maintained.

```
tab2 <- apply(tab1, c(1,2), function(x) {ifelse(x==0, 0, 1)})
```

Here I used a different way of expressing the transformation (equivalent, but different.  Probably less efficient, but I think more clear).  For this simple case, `ifelse` will preserve the dimensions.

```
tab2b <- ifelse(tab1==0, 0, 1)
```

These give the same results

```
> identical(tab2, tab2b)
[1] TRUE
```

This works even if the transformation does not preserve dimensions.

```
> as.character(tab1)
 [1] "0" "3" "0" "0" "0" "2" "0" "0" "4" "1" "5" "1" "0" "5" "2" "1" "0" "3" "0"
[20] "3" "9" "0" "4" "2" "0"
> apply(tab1, c(1,2), as.character)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "0"  "2"  "5"  "1"  "9" 
[2,] "3"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0" 
[3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "3"  "4" 
[4,] "0"  "4"  "5"  "0"  "2" 
[5,] "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing only

```
> tab2 <- (tab1!=0)+0
```

It will work.

```
> tab1 <- rbind(c(0, 2, 5, 1, 9),
+               c(3, 0, 1, 0, 0),
+               c(0, 0, 0, 3, 4),
+               c(0, 4, 5, 0, 2),
+               c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0))
> tab2 <- (tab1!=0)+0
> 
> tab1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    5    1    9
[2,]    3    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    3    4
[4,]    0    4    5    0    2
[5,]    0    1    2    3    0
> tab2
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0    1
[5,]    0    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: How is that different from mbq comment? Multiplying by one or adding zero is just shorthand for using `as.integer`. One could argue `as.integer` is slightly more efficient, but for such application it is pointless to argue.

Comment: I did not see the comment, I am sorry.